# How to use mapfile/readarray

Tags: bash, here-string

I have some code similar to this:

```
while read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 TRASH; do 
        echo -e "${col1}\n${col2}\n${col3}\n${col4}\n${col5}\n${col6}\n"
done< <(ll | tail -n+2 | head -2)
```

(I'm not actually using `ls` / `ll` but I believe this redacted example displays the same issue I am having)

The problem is I need a conditional statement if `ll | tail -n+2 | head -2` fails so I'm trying to create a mapfile instead and then `read` through it in a script.  The mapfile gets created properly but I don't know how to redirect it in order to be properly read.

**code**

```
if ! mapfile -t TEST_ARR < <(ll | tail -n+2 | head -2); then
        exit 1
fi
while read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 TRASH; do 
        echo -e "${col1}\n${col2}\n${col3}\n${col4}\n${col5}\n${col6}\n"
done<<<"${TEST_ARR[@]}"
```

**mapfile contents**

```
declare -a TEST_ARR=(
        [0]="drwxr-xr-x@ 38 wheel   1.2K Dec  7 07:10 ./" 
        [1]="drwxr-xr-x  33 wheel   1.0K Jan 18 07:05 ../"
)
```

**output**

```
$ while read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 TRASH; do
>             echo -e "${col1}\n${col2}\n${col3}\n${col4}\n${col5}\n${col6}\n"
>     done<<<"${TEST_ARR[@]}"
drwxr-xr-x@
38
wheel
1.2K
Dec
7
```

String redirect is clearly wrong in this case but I'm not sure how else I can redirect my array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that you're wanting to loop through your array, reading the elements into columns:

```
for ele in "${TEST_ARR[@]}"
do
  read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 TRASH <<< "$ele"
  echo -e "${col1}\n${col2}\n${col3}\n${col4}\n${col5}\n${col6}\n"
done
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't aware I could use `read` that way and had a method for setting all my variables with `awk` but it would not have been efficient.  This is great!

Answer (score 3):

`mapfile` reads the contents of a file to an array, and if you use `"${array[@]}"` in a context like an assignment or `<<<` that takes only a single string, it concatenates all the array elements to a single string. A bit like `"${array[*]}"`, except `@` joins with spaces, and `*` with the first character of `IFS`.

Now, you said you "created a mapfile", but I don't think that's how the command name is supposed to be interpreted. It's more like that it "maps" a file to an array. (Except that it's a copy, not a two-way mapping like it might be in some languages.) The alternative name of `readarray` is probably more accurate.